# How do I create the database files when using MySQL as an embedded server

Tags: c++, mysql, macos, embedded-database

I'm attempting to build an application which will use a MySQL embedded database (currently on OS X, but ultimately on both OS X and Windows), and I'm using [this example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/libmysqld-example.html) as a starting point.  I've successfully been able to build it, using cmake with this CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

project(Demo)

set(TARGET_NAME Demo)

add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} test2_libmysqld.cpp)

target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME}
  PRIVATE /usr/local/include/mysql
  )

find_library(LIBMYSQLD NAMES libmysqld.a)
find_library(LIBSSL NAMES libssl.a PATHS /Users/stebro/test/openssl/openssl)
find_library(LIBCRYPTO NAMES libcrypto.a PATHS /Users/stebro/test/openssl/openssl)

# target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC ${LIBMYSQLD_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME}
  ${LIBMYSQLD}
  ${LIBSSL}
  ${LIBCRYPTO}
  )
```

(I built ssl locally in /Users/stebro/test/openssl, and I had to change the name of the demo file to .cpp in order for cmake to create the proper linkages to STL & other runtime stuff.  I'm using mysql installed via homebrew which is "mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for osx10.10 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper").

When I run the program, I get the error:

```
bash$ ./Demo --defaults-file=../my.cnf
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
mysql_real_connect failed: Unknown database 'test'
```

my.cnf looks like this:

```
[Demo_SERVER]
language = /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.19/share/mysql/english

[libmysqd_server]
datadir = ./data
language = ./english
skip-innodb

[libmysqld_client]
language = ./english
```

I'm assuming this error is happening because the test is attempting to connect to a database "test", but I've never taken any steps to create this database (or any other files needed by the embedded server).

How to I create the starting file state for the embedded server to function correctly?  Do I create a database on my local MySQL instance with instructions like [these](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Database-in-MySQL), then shut down that server & copy the files over to some local space?  Or are apis in the mysqld server library I use to create the initial files (and subsequent database "test")?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, misconfiguration on my part.  The my.cnf file I was using was a merge of two different examples I found online.  The correct my.cnf file for my example looks like this:

```
[test2_libmysqld_SERVER]
language = /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.19/share/mysql/english
datadir = ./data

[test2_libmysqld_CLIENT]
language = /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.19/share/mysql/english
```

The demo program now works with the operation on connection "two" (which connects without a database specifier), but still fails on "one", but that is because no "test" db has been yet created - I think I can figure that one out.